# extract sub parameters from array with objects

Tags: javascript

I have next array:

```
let someArr = [
{param:{name: 'bla'}},
{param:{name: 'blu'}}
];
```

how I can get array without  'param'?

```
[{name: 'bla'},{name: 'blu'}]
```

Comment: Try `someArr.map(i => i.param)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let someArr = [
{param:{name: 'bla'}},
{param:{name: 'blu'}}
];

const result = someArr.map(el => el.param);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArray = someArr.map(item => {
  return item.param;
});
```